# Run Google Apps Script without authentification

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Google Sheet open for everyone 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H3slbaG_p6u3NihRDJfPECGF_teVoi-DGyJkDM5japg/edit#gid=0

And I have Google Apps Script that generates XML based on this Sheet.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbza3jI02E9zQDB-VoVBrxpHTUq8QUY2lVrUd1bGuf5q5L7jOybq/exec

So can I allow everyone get result of this script without authentification?

Comment: Authorization is based on the scope of the script. If you're using `SpreadsheetApp` or the like, you cannot run without the user authorizing. Posting your code (link requires access rights) to the question would let us give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can allow everyone use your script by doing following changes :

1. Making Spreadsheet Open for everyone (Give Edit rights to Anyone with Link)
2. Attach script to that Spreadsheet (Open that Spreadsheet>Tools>Script Editor) and execute the script at least once to authorize it on your behalf.

If this doesn't work or you need anymore assistance then kindly let me know in comments.